# How can I set ARIA HTML tags for combobox items in Java - Wicket?

Tags: java, html, wicket, wai-aria

I need to add tag 'role="menuitem"' to items generated by Wicket in a drop-down field. I believe that tags for the combo-box itself can be set with onComponentTag, but I have no idea whether it could be applied to the menu items (`<ul><li><a>`...) themselves.

Comment: Are you using a `DropDownChoice`? Because a `DropDownChoice` is using a `<select>` tag and fills it with `<option>` tags by default not `<li><a>` tags as you state.

Comment: We are using a custom class extending DropDownChoice, I have checked again and a list of <ul> -> <li> -> <a> is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said by oh-god-spiders DropDownChoice is designed to work with `<select>` and `<option>` tags. For a ARIA menu componet `ListView` might be a better choice.
In any case, if you want to enrich `DropDownChoice` options you could override `setOptionAttributes` method and add the desired attribute. For example:

```
@Override
protected void setOptionAttributes(AppendingStringBuffer buffer, E choice, int index, String selected)
    {
        super.setOptionAttributes(buffer, choice, index, selected);
        buffer.append("role=\"menuitem\" ");
     ...
```

Comment: Normally this would be all needed. Unfortunately we use Bootstrap with the Wicket and the resulting code looks like this:

`...
<select ... style="display: none>
  <option1>
  <option2>
</select>
<div class= (bootstrap button)>
  <ul>
    <li><a>option1</a></li>
    <li><a>option2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...`

So overriding setOptionalAttributes changes the options in select element, which are not displayed, while <li> elements are left intact. I will have to look in the Bootstrap integration.

However you have answered the question as I had asked it, thank you for that!